# Retrieve Postmeta in Custom WordPress Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a custom query which looks as follows:

```
<?php
$querystr = "SELECT *, SUM(`total_votes`) AS tv
FROM `toptr_bpvm_summary`,`toptr_posts`
WHERE 1
AND toptr_bpvm_summary.postid = toptr_posts.ID
AND toptr_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND toptr_bpvm_summary.post_type = 'cars'
AND toptr_bpvm_summary.vote_type=1
AND toptr_bpvm_summary.vote_date BETWEEN now() - interval 1 day
AND now()
GROUP BY `postid`
ORDER BY tv DESC limit 0, 3";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
?>
<?php if ($pageposts): ?>
<?php global $post; ?>
<?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post);?>
      <p class="postmetadata"><?php echo $post->tv ?></p>
      <p><a class="link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>  
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically it's sorting and displaying results based on their like votes from the last 24 hours in a DESC order which is working perfectly fine, see here the output if I do an r_print:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [postid] => 31 [tv] => 50000000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [postid] => 311 [tv] => 8000 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [postid] => 314 [tv] => 500 ) )
```

However I am a little bit stuck now as I would like to show additional information such as the post name, permalink etc:

```
<p><a class="link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>
```

However it's simply not displaying. The only data that actually displays is echo $post->tv

I've tried to modify my query to include `toptr_postmeta` as follows:

```
FROM `toptr_bpvm_summary`,`toptr_posts`,`toptr_postmeta`
```

However after doing that the results are just completely wrong:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [postid] => 31 [tv] => 101350000000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [postid] => 311 [tv] => 16216000 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [postid] => 314 [tv] => 1013500 )
```

I am sure there is something wrong in the main query, however I just can't seem to get my head around it. Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much in advance for any help, lead or suggestion.

Comment: You can use get_the_title($post->postid) and get_the_permalink($post->postid) to get the title and permalink respecively.

Comment: Also instead of "select *", select only the fields that you need (for better query performance). You can also select toptr_posts.post_title, toptr_posts.post_content and get them in the query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `setup_postdata` needs to take a `WP_Post` object or something WordPress can convert into one, which is either an object with an `ID` property or just an `int`. The object you are getting has `postid`, however, which WordPress knows nothing about.

One option is to try grouping by `ID` instead of `postid` which might work.

```php
$querystr = "SELECT *, SUM(`total_votes`) AS tv
FROM `toptr_bpvm_summary`,`toptr_posts`
WHERE 1
AND toptr_bpvm_summary.postid = toptr_posts.ID
AND toptr_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND toptr_bpvm_summary.post_type = 'cars'
AND toptr_bpvm_summary.vote_type=1
AND toptr_bpvm_summary.vote_date BETWEEN now() - interval 1 day
AND now()
GROUP BY `toptr_posts.ID`
ORDER BY tv DESC limit 0, 3";
```

The other option is to just call `setup_postdata($post->postid)`. If you do this, however, I'd encourage you to rename `$post` so that someone in the future (which may or may not be you) understands that it isn't a "real" `WP_Post` object.

**Edit**: This might not be 100% correct, but hopefully it gets you close. If not, you can trace [`setup_postdata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/setup_postdata/) to [`get_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) to [`sanitize_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post/)

Comment: Thank you Chris for pointing me in the right direction, appreciate your help! :)